# No files were downloaded for org.springframework:org.springframework.core:3.2.2.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I created a small java application using intellij, later I updated that project as Maven project using "Add framework support" option. When I tired to add spring jar file on project I got following error saying,"No files were downloaded for org.springframework:org.springframework.core:3.2.2.RELEASE".

Following are the steps I did to add spring jar files

1)Clicked on File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Clicked on "+" Sign -> Library -> From Maven

2)Searched for org.springframework.core and selected 3.2.2 Release

3)Downloaded to lib folder under my project.

4)Got Error.

I don't know where it went wrong. I am new to java and spring application.

Comment: Spring 3.2 is veeeerrrry old. Unless you have to use that exact version switch to 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, Maven downloads dependencies itself (a reason why it's a *build automation tool*).

To add Spring as a dependency, add this code to Maven's pom.xml (the file is in your module's root directory):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also, delete the lib directory from your project root - Maven doesn't put jars there.

Answer (score 0):

Maven downloads the dependencies automatically, can you try adding this to the pom.xml file. Maven should automatically download the dependencies..

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tired this way and it will create a xml file under .idea->libraries. How do I get jar files?